# Catching a BadPaddingException (Java)

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to implement (For a uni project) an authentication system for bitcoin transactions based on digital signatures (To create them, I'm using a combination of SHA-256 and RSA). I first create two pairs of RSA keys, (sk1,pk1) and (sk2,pk2), that respectively belong to User1 and User2:

```
KeyPair pair1 = generator.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey sk1 = pair1.getPrivate();
PublicKey pk1 = pair1.getPublic();
KeyPair pair2 = generator.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey sk2 = pair2.getPrivate();
PublicKey pk2 = pair2.getPublic();

String msg1 = "Hello world!";
```

Then I tried to simulate a fraudulent User1 signature by encrypting the message with sk2 and then decrypting with pk1, and this is the exception I get:

```
byte[] msg1_digest = functionSHA.hash(msg1);
byte[] msg1_DS = algorithmRSA.encrypt(msg1_digest, sk2);
byte[] DS_decrypted = algorithmRSA.decrypt(msg1_DS, pk1);
System.out.println("Digest comparison: " + MessageDigest.isEqual(msg1_digest, DS_decrypted));

javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:378)
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:290)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:359)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:392)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2205)
    at RSA.decrypt(RSA.java:22)
    at Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Apparently, when I encrypt with a different secret key, the code might print this message. To address this issue, I tried to use try/catch in my verification function:

```
    public void VerifyTransaction(Transaction t) {
        NetworkUser sender = t.sender; //We get the sender
        PublicKey senderPK = sender.PublicKeyRSA; //We get its public key
        byte[] transactionDS = t.digitalSignature; //We get the digital signature
        byte[] contentDigest = functionSHA.hash(t.content); //We obtain the content digest using SHA256
        try {
            byte[] DS_decrypted = algorithmRSA.decrypt(transactionDS, senderPK); //We decrypt the digital signature with the sender pk
            if (MessageDigest.isEqual(contentDigest, DS_decrypted)){
                System.out.println("Transaction approved!");}
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid signature. Transaction rejected.");
            }
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid signature. Transaction rejected.");
        }
    }
}
```

but then it complains, saying that BadPaddingException is never thrown in the try statement. Maybe it is a stupid mistake of mine, but any help is highly appreciated :)

I expected for the try and catch to be legit on the code.
p.s: This is the RSA class, along with the main:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;

public class RSA {
    //Encryption function. From a String, returns a byte sequence 'byte[]' object as output
    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, PrivateKey keyValue){
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyValue);
            return cipher.doFinal(data);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    //Decryption function. From byte[], returns a byte sequence 'byte[]' object as output. Use string constructor to derive back the original message
    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, PublicKey keyValue){
        try{
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyValue);
            return cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.*;

public class Main {
    //Instances of SHA256, RSA, and its KeyPairGenerator
    static SHA256 functionSHA = new SHA256();
    static RSA algorithmRSA = new RSA();
    static KeyPairGeneratorRSA generator = new KeyPairGeneratorRSA();

    static KeyPair pair1 = generator.generateKeyPair();
    static PrivateKey sk1 = pair1.getPrivate();
    static PublicKey pk1 = pair1.getPublic();
    static KeyPair pair2 = generator.generateKeyPair();
    static PrivateKey sk2 = pair2.getPrivate();
    static PublicKey pk2 = pair2.getPublic();

    static String msg1 = "Hello world!";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte[] msg1_digest = functionSHA.hash(msg1);
        byte[] msg1_DS = algorithmRSA.encrypt(msg1_digest, sk2);
        byte[] DS_decrypted = algorithmRSA.decrypt(msg1_DS, pk1);
        System.out.println("Digest comparison: " + MessageDigest.isEqual(msg1_digest, DS_decrypted));

}
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the complete `RSA` class and your main method? It seems like the exception is unrelated to `VerifyTransaction`.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the post

Comment: Encryption on asymmetric encryption is done with the **public key** and Decryption is done with the **Private/Secret key**. OR do you want to generate a signature (as written in your first sentence) ? Then use the **Private/Secret key** for calculating the signature and the **Public key** for verifying the signature ?

Comment: I generate digital signatures based on the transactions content (In the post above, I used hello world as an example), thus I encrypt the message digest with the secret key and I decrypt with the public one. The code should print "Transaction approved" only when the digest matches the one obtained by decrypting the digital signature with the sender's pk

Comment: You catch the exception in `decrypt()`, so it doesn't drop down the call stack to the previous method, see e.g. [Java Exception Propagation](https://www.javatpoint.com/exception-propagation). By the way, your signing does not comply with the standard (RFC8017). For that you would have to use `Signature#sign()/verify()`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Topaco notes, you already catch the exception in `decrypt()` so it can't be caught higher up.

Possibly more directly to the point, the code should not compile since you don't declare that `decrypt()` `throws` `BadPaddingException`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html , and this is probably what you mean when you say:

> it complains, saying that BadPaddingException is never thrown in the try statement